# Contact annotation does not work for converted application

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

We have WPF app converted using "Centennial" project. And we are using UWP Contacts API to add annotation for contact(https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ContactCardIntegration). All works fine, but nothing happens when user tap on button "Call on an app" in "People" app.

Our app supports "ms-voip-call" protocol in app manifest:

```
<uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
   <uap:Protocol Name="ms-voip-call">
       <uap:DisplayName>appname</uap:DisplayName>
   </uap:Protocol>
 </uap:Extension>
```

Moreover protocol works fine when I use direct link for testing.
UWP sample works fine.

I did not find this problem in known issues of "Centennial". So, I do not have idea what is wrong. Maybe somebody can give me advice.

Comment: The UWP protocol extension can activate only UWP components, so you would have to add one of those to your package to handle the activation. From there you can then trigger the WPF app to perform the required action.

Comment: https://github.com/stammen/BuildTourHack/blob/master/stories/2/221_XAMLView.md

Comment: Posted this as answer now. Please accept when you get a chance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UWP protocol extension can activate only UWP components, so you would have to add one of those to your package to handle the activation. From there you can then trigger the WPF app to perform the required action.

Here is a related example:
https://github.com/stammen/BuildTourHack/blob/master/stories/2/221_XAMLView.md